# Найти в заданном числе нужную цифру

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Есть массив чисел. Мне надо проверить этот массив на наличие чисел, в состав которых входит цифра 6. Я делаю перебор массива циклом `for` .Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше всего сделать? сравнивать каждое число с регулярным выражением или есть другой способ?

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var n = 6;
for(var i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++){
    var sort[] = numbers[i];
    if(numbers[i].search(n)){
        delete(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65065/discussion-between-grundy-and-kittycat-13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса `Array` есть метод `map`, который принимает параметром callback функцию, для каждого элементы массива вызывает эту функцию и на основании возвращенных результатов формирует новый массив.

У объекта `RegExp` есть метод `test`, который проверяет соответствует ли переданный аргумент регулярному выражению.

Проверить число на наличие в нем цифры `6` можно регулярным выражением `/6/`. Или выражением `/6/.test(num)`

Итого получаем код

```js
let a = [10, 76, 98, 675, 983, 8765];
let b = a.map(function(val) {
  if (/6/.test(val))
    return 0;
  return val;
});
console.log(b);
```

Comment: добавь описание, что происходит в коде :)

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Answer (score 3):

```js
let m = [45612,56484,89745].filter(n => String(n).indexOf(6) != -1);

console.log(...m);
```

Если нужно заменять число как сказано в комментариях то

```js
let a = [45612,56484,89745].map(n => Number(String(n).replace(/6/g, 5)));

console.log(...a);
```

Comment: `? false : true` :(

Comment: @Qwertiy почему-то только сейчас дошло)

Comment: Во втором варианте результат будет массивом строк, а не чисел

Comment: Пользуясь случаем, объясните что значат 3 точки в выводе: `console.log(...a);`

Comment: @Swartex, [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо